# Pandas.to_numeric issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file which, when opened in notepad, displays the following format:

[image]. As you can see, it is just a 1 column file with 2 values but there are no commas within the actual file When reading this file into pandas as `df = pd.read_csv(f)`, it is treating the Amount values as strings. Since I'm trying to convert the two 70 values as floats, I am using `df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'])` with `df.to_excel(newfile, index = False)` but it returns a blank 5kb excel file. I added `errors="ignore"` to the `pd.to_numeric` and it returns the two 70 values as strings. When using `errors="coerce"`, it returns NaN values in the console.

I believe the issue lies in the format of the CSV file itself. Although it shows as a CRLF file at the bottom right when the original file is opened in notepad, I believe it was first a Unix LF file and just opened, saved, and closed using Excel, forcing the change from LF to CRLF. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you expecting the file to look like ?

Comment: @AchilleHuet I'm trying to read in the csv file in Pandas, set the Amount column to a float datatype, and then save it as an excel file. When I open the file in excel, the expectation is that the values in the Amount column are decimal numbers and not strings. Thanks for the clarification question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem with dollar sign while converting to float:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'])
```

> ValueError: Unable to parse string "($70.00)" at position 0

After I removed the dollar sign and square brackets, it worked for me.

```
df["Amount"] = df["Amount"].replace(regex={r'[$\)]': '', '[\(]': '-'}).astype(float)
print(df['Amount'])
```

> 0    -70.0
>
> 1    70.0
> Name: Amount, dtype: float64

Now you can write it to an excel file.

Comment: I don't know why this is a good answer. The brackets are usually interpreted to mean a negative value: `(70.00)` maps to `-70`. https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/1875. Discarding that and deciding that it's positive, as the answer above does, would introduce a possible data error. @pilotmike327 @Hamzah

Comment: I have no idea about the meaning of brackets in the finance world, but you can preprocess all negative numbers with ( )  by replacing ( ) with a negative sign and then converting them to a float type. Otherwise, you cannot define a float column to do some mathematical operations with the brackets ( ).

Comment: @ifly6 I did the jump the gun and realize that there was an issue with the output. thank you for pointing that out. I do believe Hamzah's suggestion of using .replace is moving me towards the endgoal, I just need to mess with it a bit more. Thanks again

Comment: I edited the solution with a simple replacement after your note regarding the meaning of ( ) in the finance world.

Answer (score 0):

I identify where it is negative then adjust after the fact.

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('Amount\n($70)\n$70'))
>>> df['is_negative'] = df['Amount'].str.match('\(\$?\d+(.\d+)?\)')

>>> raw_amount = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'].str.replace(r'[\(\)\$]', '', regex=True)
>>> df['num'] = np.where(df['is_negative'], -1 * raw_amount, raw_amount) 
>>> df
 
  Amount  num  is_negative
0  ($70)  -70         True
1    $70   70        False
```